# Значение this.el остается undefined при изменении

Tags: backbone.js, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Имеется вьюшка:

```
var SessionView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#main_content"),

template: JST["main"],

render: function()
{
    $(this.el).html(this.template);
    return this;
}
});

var view = new SessionView();
```

И роутер:

```
var ProfileRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
   routes: {
     "main": "main"
   },
   main: function(){
      view.render();
   }
});
```

В итоге:
**this.el** равен **undefined**, и тем самым шаблон не рендерится.
Но если **$(this.el).html(this.template);** заменить на **$("#main_content").html(this.template);** - то все работает.

Пробовал использовать **this.$el.html()** - он тоже не рендериться, хотя селектор указывает верный

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Comment: А в отладчике во время выполнения `this` на что указывает? Посмотри, может и проблему найдешь

Comment: Что либо указывающее на ошибку не нашел, вот часть:  
$el: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[0]  
context: HTMLDocument  
selector: "#main_content"  
proto: Object[0]  
cid: "view2"  
el: undefined  

Template компилиться нормально, но вот el = undefined

Comment: код находится выполняется `$(document).ready`? просто других причин, почему `$("#main_content") - undefined` не видно. к тому же `this.el` у вас уже jQuery object так что использование `$(this.el)` избыточно

Comment: "код выполняется в $(document).ready" - да  

this.el равен undefined  
Но хоть this.$el является Jquery обьектом все равно не работает.

Comment: если вы утверждаете, что `$("#main_content").html(this.template);` работает, то следует, что во время вызова `view.render();`, `#main_content` существует, но во время выполнения `var view = new SessionView();` - нет, т.к. `el: $("#main_content")` возвращает undefined. какой версией backbone пользуетесь?

Comment: Версия 0.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Роитинг и создание Backbone histrory происходит в $(document).ready, а new SessionView перенес в роутинг при рендереге, но все так же и осталось.

То что SessionView не видит id #main_content видимо из-за того что он подключается до рендеринга html, но если View обрамлять $(document).ready - то роутер просто не находит его.

Перенес подключение js файлов в конец страницы и this.el - заработал. Спасибо вам за помощь и наведение в правильную сторону размышления.